# MySQL индексы и неравенства

Tags: mysql, sql, индексы

Есть запрос с подзапросом, который считает количество клиентов за сутки до текущей заявки:

```
select fm.credit_id,
    fm.date_requested,

    (select count(*) from monitoring_v1 fm1
        where fm1.borrower_id <> fm.borrower_id
            and fm1.credit_id < fm.credit_id
            and fm1.date_requested between fm.date_requested - interval 1 day and fm.date_requested
    ) + 1 as borrowers_1d
from monitoring_v1 fm
where date(fm.date_requested) = curdate()
```

В БД стоят индексы на столбцы `date_requested` и составной индекс на `credit_id, borrower_id`. Запрос отрабатывает очень медленно, как будто индексы не помогают при неравенствах, а работают только при равенстве в условии.

explain:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно оптимизировать выполнение запроса?

Comment: Переписать на соединение таблиц. Сможете? `Range checked for each record` - ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: Представьте, у вас есть двоичное дерево поиска. Как бы вы по этому дереву отработали неравенство ? Это просмотр всего дерева, кроме одной ветки. Это не целесообразно. По credit_id< видимо записей слишком много. Я бы попробовал индекс (credit_id, date_requested) если не поможет, то (date_requested, credit_id). Хотя не понимаю почему он чистый date_requested не использует.

Comment: Что касается основной части запроса, то вы `date(fm.date_requested) = curdate()` написали специально, что бы индекс было невозможно использовать ? `fm.date_requested >= curdate() and fm.date_requested < curdate()+interval 1 day` предпочтителен

Comment: @TotalPusher конечно, но подзапросы стабильно быстрее отрабатывают в кейсе с неравенствами.

Comment: `подзапросы стабильно быстрее отрабатывают в кейсе с неравенствами` - откуда такое суждение? я всегда считал, что подзапрос - это убийца любой оптимизации. Было бы интересно прочитать, если это так.

Comment: @TotalPusher суждение, основанное на опыте написания запросов. Когда работал с ораклом, тоже так думал, начал работу в MySQL - часто стал писать подзапросы, когда нельзя прописать `join` с равенством.

Comment: @Mike ну, примерно так и думал, что при неравенстве ему необходимо смотреть бОльшую часть дерева. Добавил указанные вами индексы - не помогло, к сожалению. Принудительное использование `use index(index_name)` тоже не привело к ускорению выполнения запроса. Кстати, как ни странно, при `fm.date_requested >= curdate() and fm.date_requested < curdate()+interval 1 day` в explain видит индекс, но время выполнения не меняется.

Comment: @Denis, неплохо было бы предоставить `SHOW CREATE TABLE monitoring_v1` и `EXPLAIN запроса`, желательно в виде текста, а не картинки. Вот от этой ерунды `where date(fm.date_requested) = curdate()` избавились? Чтобы мускул индекс использовал, а не занимался подсчетами?

Comment: @TotalPusher Да, убрал, индекс в `where` видит, но время выполнения осталось то же. Таблицу создавал как `create table monitoring_v1 as select ... from ...`, потом сверху навесил индексы и pk, там много `varchar(...)` столбцов и `bigint(22)` типа `borrower_id bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL`.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть `SHOW CREATE TABLE monitoring_v1`. `date(fm.date_requested) = curdate()` можно переписать на `fm.date_requested = что-то-там(curdate())`. Но вот на что? Там datetime? Текст? Схему в студию. Время как замеряете? Правильно через SQL_NO_CACHE (или другой способ выключить кеш) или неправильно?